# Vertical and horizontal alignment of input field in a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Could any one help me around this piece of stupid code where I lost almost 2hours trying to figure out how to make it work. Goal is to center input field verticaly and horizontaly inside horizontal bar.

Here is a simplified code:

HTML:

```
<div class="navigationBar">
    <input type="text" id="searchField">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigationBar{
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(102,102,102);
}

#searchField{
    margin; auto;
    height: 25px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

I've also tried with display modes, changing position types but no luck.

Here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/DJa25/10/)

Comment: I don't know the reason of the downvote, but its working here: http://jsfiddle.net/acor/utr5q2bt/

Comment: I have managed to make it work. Here is a[link] (http://jsfiddle.net/DJa25/12/). But when I upload it to the server it's still not verticaly aligned

Comment: negative margins are not the best for aligning

Comment: I've seen that on the twitter site.

Comment: Every time you change the width of your element, you need to change the margin as well. Is up to you

Answer (score 0):

Adding a line-height wil make it centered vertically.

```
.navigationBar{
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(102,102,102);
}

#seachfield
    margin; 0, auto;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Try to add this line into the rest of code. It seems that it's not working.

Comment: Try setting margin to 0 auto for searchfield

Answer (score 0):

add `display:block;`

```
#searchField{
    display:block;
    margin: 2px auto;
    height: 25px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**margin auto: top and left**
add `'text-align: center;'`=> (not only alignment text)

```
.navigationBar{
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(102,102,102);
    text-align: center;
}
#searchField{
    height: 25px;
    width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:4px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple, just remove padding for #nav element and set his height and line-height to 40px and then set display: inline-block for #search

```css
 #nav {
 line-height: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 }
#search {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below CSS:

```
.navigationBar{
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(102,102,102);
    position:relative;
}

#searchField{
    margin: auto;
    height: 25px;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px;
}
```

PS : its not `margin; auto;`, the correct syntax is `margin: auto;`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DJa25/11/)

Answer (score -1):

2 ways to do it
second way is actually using latest css features so , take care

1.)

```
.navigationBar {    position: relative;}

 #searchField {    width: 300px;    
                   height: 100px;    
                   padding: 20px;    
                   position: absolute;
                   top: 50%;    
                   left: 50%;    
                   margin: -70px 0 0 -170px;
              }
```

2.)

```
.navigationBar {    position: relative;}

 #searchField {     position: absolute;    
                    top: 50%;    
                    left: 50%;    
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              }
```